# How to count the occurrence of permutations in a data set in R?

Tags: r, count, dataset, permutation

I have a question on how to count the occurrence of specified permuations in a data set in R.

I am currently working on continuous-glucose-monitoring data sets. Shortly, each data set has between 1500 to 2000 observations (each observation is a plasma glucose value measured every 5 minutes over 6 days).

I need to count the occurrence of glucose values below 3.9 occurring for 15 minutes or more and less than 120 minutes in a row (>3 observations and <24 observations for values <3.9 in a row) on a numeric scale.

I have made a new variable with a factor 1 or 0 for whether the plasma glucose value is below 3.9 or not.

I would then like to count the number of occurrences of permutations > three 1’s in a row and < twenty-four 1’s in a row.

Is there a function in R for this or what would be the easiest approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It might be helpful to add some code already, else the question might be out of scope of the portal but more a question for https://superuser.com/ or another portal on this site: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: I think a minimal reproducible example would greatly benefit this question

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i got your data-structure right, but maybe the following code still can help

I'm assuming a data-structure that includes Measurement, person-id and measurement-id.

```
library(dplyr)
# create dumy-data
set.seed(123)
data_test = data.frame(measure = rnorm(100, 3.5,2), person_id = rep(1:10, each = 10), measure_id = rep(1:10, 10))

data_test$below_criterion = 0 # indicator for measures below crit-value
data_test$below_criterion[which(data_test$measure < 3.9)] = 1 # indicator for measures below crit-value

# indicator, that shows if the current measurement is the first one below crit_val in a possible series
# shift columns, to compare current value with previous one
data_test = data_test %>% group_by(person_id) %>% mutate(prev_below_crit = c(below_criterion[1], below_criterion[1:(n()-1)]))
data_test$start_of_run = 0 # create the indicator variable
data_test$start_of_run[which(data_test$below_criterion == 1 & data_test$prev_below_crit == 0)] = 1 # if current value is below crit and previous value is above, this is the start of a series
data_test = data_test %>% group_by(person_id) %>% mutate(grouper = cumsum(start_of_run)) # helper-variable to group all the possible series within a person

data_test = data_test %>% select(measure, person_id, measure_id, below_criterion, grouper) # get rid of the previous created helper-variables

data_results = data_test %>% group_by(person_id, grouper) %>% summarise(count_below_crit = sum(below_criterion)) # count the length of each series by summing up all below_crit indicators within a person and series

data_results = data_results %>% group_by(person_id) %>% filter(count_below_crit >= 3 & count_below_crit <=24) %>% summarise(n()) # count all series within a desired length for each person
data_results

data.frame(data_test)
```